# Move cell value on alternate rows to next row and delete empty row using VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba

[image: User Selection Before processing]
[image: Selection After processing]

Based on the images above I want to be a to select a range that looks like the first image dynamically and process it into the layout of the second image.

Below is some code i have tried to execute to do this dynamically.

```
Dim Myrange As Range
Dim Myrow As Range
Set Myrange = Selection
Dim strVal As String

For Each Myrow In Myrange.Rows
If Myrow.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
strVal = Myrow.Columns(1).Cells
Myrow.Columns(1).Value = ""
Myrow.Offset(1, -1).Value = strVal
End If
Next Myrow
```

[Undesired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06aBW.png)

The last image is what i get when selection is processed.
Three cells instead of one are replaced with the values on previous row.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54890995/edit) to provide us with the first image? What you have tried so far and how it failed to achieve the desired result would also be useful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: [Unstacking data in Excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rscXNUlRsH0)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Participants is column A, put this formula in A1 and drag down.

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(B1,1)), OFFSET(B1,-1,0),"")
```